# Fade out parent li on click

Tags: jquery

I have an LI that contains a form, on form submit I want to fade out the parent LI, I've been trying with no luck, I've also made a fiddle in basic form, can anybody give me an idea on how its done?

http://jsfiddle.net/uAZ5Z/

```
<li>
<form>
    <input type='submit' value='delete'>
</form>
</li>
```

jQ:

```
 $('input').click(
     $(this).fadeOut();
 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').fadeOut();
});
​
```

You have two errors in your code:

1. There must be a call to a function (anonymous or not) inside `$.click()`.
2. `$(this)` in this context references the `<input>` element. To reference it's closest `<li>`, you need to use `$.closest()` instead. Note that you shouldn't use `$.parent()`, because it only get the direct parent of the element.

---

To make any `<li>` elements underneath the current one, instead of just doing `$.fadeOut()`, do this instead:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').slideUp();
});
```

Which will animate the element's height to 0, "sliding" it up.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much! Is there a way to get the li items beneath to slowly animate up to take up the white space as opposed to just 'jumping'? @jamwaffles

Comment: @Liam Use `slideUp` instead of `fadeOut` >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uAZ5Z/6/ <<

Comment: Thanks @Vega, I didn't realise I could do that

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/uAZ5Z/9/ )

I changed the type to "button" instead of "submit" so you stay on the same page:

```
<li>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value='delete'>
    </form>
</li>​
```

You can either get the parent of the parent, or find the closest li:

```
$('input').click( function()
{
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut();
});
```

​